# Decompose D3DXMatrixLookAtLH matrix

Tags: c++, directx

I have tried searching the function prototype but I found nothing, is there any knowledge of what this function does and for the question how to decompose it into position, lookat, up.

Comment: This is the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function creates a camera matrix at the specified position looking towards lookat with the given up-vector. It is basically a base transformation multiplied with a translation matrix (first the orientation via base transformation and after moved to the camera position)

The position can be computed with the last row (3-components). You must multiply each negated component with the respective column (only the first 3-components) and sum it up for the position (thx @Nico Schertler for revealing my mistake)

The up-vector is equal to the second column (3-components).
The lookat can't be computed, but you can get the viewdirection with the third column (3-components). The original lookat lies at the ray from position with the viewdirection.

Comment: Be aware that the last row does not contain the camera's position, but its dot products with the axes. The position is then `dotX * xAxis + dotY * yAxis + dotZ * zAxis`.

Comment: Oh of course you're right, my mistake. I've updated my answer.